# SpamAssassin (spampd) ignoring user_prefs

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, spamassassin

I have an Ubuntu (12.10) server running postfix and SpamAssassin. I've set up spampd following  these directions on the SpamAssassin wiki:
http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/IntegratePostfixViaSpampd

However, settings ~/.spamassassin/user_prefs are being ignored.

What do I need to do to have spampd/SpamAssassin read/use per-user rules?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not 100% clear on whether spampd is calling spamassassin or spamc, if it is calling spamc you need to set `allow_user_rules` to 1, if not, it should look for the user_prefs in the directory of the user calling spamassassin, and that directory only.

I don't think you will be able to use individual user_prefs from in spampd, they specifically mention that per-user whitelists are not available. They also mention that per-user preferences are a To-Do..

**From the notes on switches**

> Turns on the SpamAssassin global whitelist feature.  See the SA docs.
>   Note that per-user whitelists are not available.

**From the To-Do section on github**

> Per-user preferences: The jury is still out on this one.  I'm thinking
>   more and more that most per-user prefs should be specified on the
>   final mailbox server.  Why? Because SMTP isn't designed with per-user
>   preferences in mind. On a relay server, the same message body can go
>   to multiple recipients who may have wildly different preferences when
>   it comes to handilng junk mail.  The exception here might be the use
>   of LMTP protocol, which bears further investigation.

I'm guessing they assume the users will have .procmail filters.

Comment: BTW, if you want per-user spamassassin prefs, have a look at calling it from amavisd, you can have them in SQL, and let users change preferences through web apps including webmail programs..

Comment: Per the docs I linked to, this is using SpamAssassin and not `spamc`. I'm not asking for a whitelist; I'm asking for general use of user_prefs, so different users can have different thresholds, etc.

Comment: It sounds like amavisd a newer/better approach to solving this problem.

Comment: Yeah, either you have each user call spamassassin so spamassassin runs in their context, or you use spamc/spamd and specifically enable per-user rulesets, or you call spamc/d from amavis, etc, and use their methods for importing specific user settings.

Comment: BTW, I mention per-user whitelists, as that is one of the primary functionalities that I saw used from my webmail interface to amavis/SQL, and it's one of the most common things that users want to be able to enable in their personal preferences. Maybe I should have mentioned that in the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

What are the permission settings on your user_prefs file? Verify that its readable by the spam assassin daemon. They should probably be 644.

Failing that, what user are you running SA as? According to [this resource here](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2007/01/msg03725.html), certain usergroups for the daemon result in it checking for config files in /home/spamassassin. Admittedly, this is Debian, so the Ubuntu behavior might be different.

Comment: /home, /home/paul, /home/paul/.spamassassin are 744 and /home/paul/.spamassassin/user_prefs is 644. `spampd` is running as the user `spampd`.

There is no /home/spamassassin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `-u ${recipient}` argument for spamc in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
    user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -u ${recipient} -f -e  
    /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```